# How do I search a Boost::interprocess::map stored within a Boost::managed_shared_memory segment as open_read_only?

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a Boost:interprocess::unordered_map that has a Key of type string and Value of type string.  That map is stored in a managed_shared_memory segment.  I'm attempting to restrict access to these segments, so the segment is created with rw-rw-r--.  The idea is the owner and related group would have read/write access, and 'other' would be restricted to read only.

This works fine if I open_read_only and iterate through the map manually.  All of the data is present across processes.  I ran into issues when attempting to use mymap->find() or mymap->at(), because both functions require the basic_string (w/ allocator) be passed.

When I attempt to create a basic_string to use in find() or at(), I get an access violation error.

```
char_string tmpKey(searchKey, alloc_inst); // Access violation crash.
```

Is there a way to use find() or at() without the basic_string? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Header

```
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<char, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> CharAllocator;
typedef boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> char_string;
typedef char_string KeyType;
typedef char_string MappedType;
typedef std::pair<const char_string, char_string> ValueType;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<ValueType, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef boost::unordered_map<KeyType, MappedType, boost::hash<KeyType>, std::equal_to<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MyShmMap;
```

Main

```
managed_shared_memory segment(open_read_only, "segment_name");
MyShmMap* mymap = segment.find<MyShmMap>("segment_name").first;
CharAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());
char_string tmpKey(searchKey, alloc_inst); // Access violation crash.
MyShmMap::iterator it = mymap->find(tmpKey);
if (it != mymap->end()) {
  auto value = mymap->at(tmpKey);
  // etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never check the pointer `mymap` is not null.

If we make sure that exists, by first executing this (once):

```
// assuming this exists
Segment s(bip::open_or_create, "segment_name", 10 * 1024);
s.find_or_construct<MyShmMap>("segment_name")(s.get_segment_manager());
```

Then it all works fine: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/070ed0e43ab4fed4)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/functional.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc  = boost::container;

using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;
template <typename K, typename V>
using UnorderedMap = boost::unordered_map<K, V, boost::hash<K>, //
                                          std::equal_to<K>,
                                          Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;

using String   = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using MyShmMap = UnorderedMap<String, String>;

int main() {
    {
        // assuming this exists
        Segment s(bip::open_or_create, "segment_name", 10 * 1024);
        s.find_or_construct<MyShmMap>("segment_name")(s.get_segment_manager());
    }

    Segment segment(bip::open_read_only, "segment_name");
    MyShmMap* mymap = segment.find<MyShmMap>("segment_name").first;

    auto it = mymap->find(String("test", segment.get_segment_manager()));
    if (it != mymap->end()) {
        auto const& value = it->second;
    }
}
```

I also took the opportunity to

- clean up your type-defs for re-usability
- note that using `.at` after `.find` is very wasteful. It's especially wasteful since you used the /shared/ string as the key.

### Smart And Efficient

You can really improve the performance by using a hash/equality comparer that is compatible with string views, and using the [advanced lookup](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id-1_3_46_10_2_1_1_44_1_3-bb):

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Hash = boost::hash<K>,
          typename EqCmp = std::equal_to<K>>
using UnorderedMap = boost::unordered_map<K, V, //
                         Hash, EqCmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;

using MyShmMap = UnorderedMap<String, String, boost::hash<std::string_view>, std::equal_to<void>>;
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd77b3469f152b6c)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/functional.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc  = boost::container;

using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;
template <typename K, typename V, typename Hash = boost::hash<K>,
          typename EqCmp = std::equal_to<K>>
using UnorderedMap = boost::unordered_map<K, V, //
                         Hash, EqCmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;

using String   = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using MyShmMap = UnorderedMap<String, String, boost::hash<std::string_view>, std::equal_to<void>>;

#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    {
        // assuming this exists
        Segment s(bip::open_or_create, "segment_name", 10 * 1024);

        auto* m = s.get_segment_manager();
        s.find_or_construct<MyShmMap>("segment_name")(m) //
            ->emplace(std::piecewise_construct,          //
                      std::tuple("stuff", m),            //
                      std::tuple("lives here", m));
    }

    Segment segment(bip::open_read_only, "segment_name");
    MyShmMap* mymap = segment.find<MyShmMap>("segment_name").first;
    auto      hash  = mymap->hash_function();
    auto      eq    = mymap->key_eq();

    if (auto it = mymap->find("stuff", hash, eq); it != mymap->end()) {
        auto const& [k,v] = *it;
        std::cout << std::quoted(k.c_str()) << " -> " << std::quoted(v.c_str()) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
"stuff" -> "lives here"
```

### Cherry On Top

To reduce the ugly of allocators like:

```
Segment s(bip::open_or_create, "segment_name", 10 * 1024);

auto* m = s.get_segment_manager();
s.find_or_construct<MyShmMap>("segment_name")(m) //
    ->emplace(std::piecewise_construct,          //
              std::tuple("stuff", m),            //
              std::tuple("lives here", m));
```

Consider [scoped allocators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/container/cpp_conformance.html#container.cpp_conformance.scoped_allocator):

```
template <typename T> using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor< //
    bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>>;
```

Now the container propagates the allocator when using the allocator to construct:

```
Segment s(bip::open_or_create, "segment_name", 10 * 1024);

auto& m = *s.find_or_construct<MyShmMap>("segment_name")(
    s.get_segment_manager());

m.emplace("stuff", "lives here");
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1211ed946fff4de8)** again.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  The first section ran into the same issue on the String constructor (access violation).  However, the hash change resolved the issue.  I'm assuming because it doesn't need an allocator, so the read only mode stays happy?

Also, thanks for introducing me to scoped allocators.  I'll read up on them and give it a test.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the segfault. Can you share the minimal self-contained example that fails? I shared [mine that works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/070ed0e43ab4fed4) which should be easy enough to modify?